# Stop HTML5 video from buffering in Safari

Tags: safari, html5-video

I have a simple HTML5 video player in a hide-able `<div>` for use on iOS devices for watching MP4 videos. If the user "closes" the player (or, in reality, hides it), I really want to kill the video entirely, preserving the user's bandwidth. The only method for halting video that I know if is `videoElement.pause()`, which does stop the video from playing, but from watching network stats it looks like the video continues to load until the entire file is complete. I've also tried `videoElement.currentTime = videoElement.duration`, but that also seems to have no impact on the buffering video.

Is there a way to kill the download? Or is this just a straight HTTP file transfer that JavaScript has no control over?

Comment: Here's a similar question with an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071872/html5-video-force-abort-of-buffering

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried emptying the src?

videoElement.pause();
videoElement.src = "";