# audio tag prevent buffer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While using HTML5 audio tag, i am having a problem.
I am using icecast2 server to stream my music.

But the problem is, browser saves the buffer when stream is played. So when the player is paused or the page is refreshed, instead of asking server for the fresh stream, it plays the previously saved buffer only. 
As i am playing live stream,  i want always fresh stream to be played. What can i do to ensure that??

What i found after browsing is- [HTML5 Video: Force abort of buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071872/html5-video-force-abort-of-buffering/13302599#13302599) 
So creating a new audio tag is an option but i am not clear on it and also i dont know if it is a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most common way to prevent caching of any HTTP resource (text files, images, audio, etc) is to append a meaningless random `GET` parameter onto the URL. So if your URL is like this:

`http://musicserver.com/livestream.mp3`

Then you'd do something like this:

`http://musicserver.com/livestream.mp3?nocache=12034981237`

Where the value of `nocache` is randomly generated each and every time. Then the browser will treat it as a new unique resource/file.

Comment: thanks for the help. so you mean i should generate a random value everytime play button is clicked and change the src attribute of source everytime? sounds like a better option... thanks!

Comment: I would change the URL every time you want it to start without using the existing cache/buffer. Sounds like that would probably be every time the play button is clicked.