# How to prevent buffering whole media file in HTML5

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, audio, jplayer

I have .mp3 in standard HTML5 media player (I also tried scripts like jPlayer). My audio is one hour long / 60MB. The problem is that I don't know how to prevent buffering WHOLE file (I'm not talking about `preload` attribute).

When I click Play, listen for ex. 5 sec and click Pause, browser download a rest 59min 50sec! This is waste of transfer of user internet and my server. For example I have also other file 4h duration, so why do I have to download the whole file, even if I want to play only first 10min? This is very annoying and I can not find any explanation using Google. How to do it like Youtube (dynamic buffering)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video: Force abort of buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071872/html5-video-force-abort-of-buffering)