# In-line videos fail to play after 6 videos

Tags: javascript, html, video

I’ve created a grid of 50 thumbnails that, when clicked, expand to play an in-line video before collapsing once the video has ended or when another thumbnail is selected.

The problem is that for some reason, after six thumbnails have been clicked, the rest fail to play.

I’ve checked to make sure that all the videos have loaded and that they all display a ready state of at least 3. There also doesn’t seem to be any rhyme or reason about which 6 videos are clicked first.

What could possibly be happening to cause this?

Comment: [Browsers have limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/985704/10304804) of max connection per server and total connections overall. -- You should [stop the loading/buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058996/10304804) when the preview is closed.